# Extracting JSON with common_schema

Tags: mysql, json, xpath, frameworks

I truly hope there is someone here who is savvy with common_schema plug-in to MySQL, which should be built on xpath.
I have a json that looks like so

`set @json:= '{"349724":{"id1":349724,"id":"14005","level":30,"up":141427}}'`

I am writing this

`SELECT common_schema.extract_json_value(@json, '/349724/id') AS result ;`

Error Code: 1105. XPATH syntax error: '349724/id'

Could you point me to the right direction here?
To me this example look totally the same as this one.
https://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/extract_json_value.html

using json_to_xml() returns this
`<349724><id1>349724</id1><id>14005</id><level>30</level><up>141427</up></349724>`

This is the snippet of the code for extract_json_value() method.

`create function extract_json_value(
       json_text text charset utf8,
       xpath text charset utf8
    ) returns text charset utf8
    comment 'Extracts JSON value via XPath'
    language SQL
    deterministic
    modifies sql data
    sql security invoker
    begin
      return ExtractValue(json_to_xml(json_text), xpath);

    end;`

Comment: `extract_json_value()` converts json to XML and XML tag name can't start with number. Try to see how your json actually get converted to XML by [json_to_xml()](https://common-schema.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/common_schema/doc/html/json_to_xml.html), post the XML result here, then we can suggest a proper xpath for that kind of XML structure

Comment: returns this `<349724><id1>349724</id1><id>14005</id><level>30</level><up>141427</up></349724>`

Comment: Awesome suggestion. So, I got into his code. And he relies on the [ExtractValue()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/xml-functions.html#function_extractvalue) that is built in mysql, which, in turn, uses xpath. that one should prohibit extraction and throw an error if the syntax of xpath is violated.

Comment: BTW, '//id' returns an empty string. The same implementation of ExtractValue() in mysql returns null if xpath is violated. `set @v:="<349724><id1>349724</id1><id>14005</id><level>30</level><up>141427</up></349724‌​>";
select ExtractValue(@v,'//id1');`